# Kubernetes Job not recognizing fsGroup in Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I've tried to add fsGroup to a Job with no luck, the generated Pod doesn't include the fsGroup in the security context.  Does a Kube Job allow for the fsGroup to be specified and then propagated to the generated Pod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Kubernetes 1.4 and successfully created a job with `fsGroup`. Maybe you misplaced `fsGroup` in your manifest? This is my manifest:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world-container
          image: hello-world
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1234
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Output from `kubectl describe job hello-world`:

```
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubobjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  4m        4m      1   {job-controller }           Normal      SuccessfulCreate    Created pod: hello-world-yzyz7
```

Output from `kubectl get pod hello-world-yzyz7 -o yaml | grep fsGroup`:

```
    fsGroup: 1234
```

Comment: you are a life saver!  I had placed the fsGroup tag in the wrong place!  many thanks.  this is the correct answer.

Comment: @JeffMcCormick If this helped you somehow, can you mark the answer as helpful? I would be very thankful.